# How to avoid warning on \ifsomething \end{document} \fi

Tags: conditionals

This is truly an unimportant curiosity/itch question.  I have chapters in a book that can compile either within the whole book or by themselves.  At the end, the files have statements like:

```
\ifchapteronly\end{document}\fi
```

This works fine but gives a warning about a nested `\if`.  I presume that there is no way to avoid it, but if there is, I would love to know.

Comment: By the way, sounds like a job for the standalone package.

Comment: Or `include/includeonly`.

Comment: thx, guys.  `\includeonly` requires changing the main file when I want to switch chapters.  the chapter approach, each self-compilable or full-in compilable, with me being able to quickly open chapter x for pdf preview works great.  I import the labels from all the other files --- voi'la.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What would be the structure of such a document?

You possibly have something like

```
%% file main.tex
\def\thisisthewholebook{}

\documentclass{book}

\input{commonsetup}

\begin{document}

\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
%...

\end{document}
```

Then you have

```
%% file commonsetup.tex

% define the conditional end
\newcommand{\maybeendhere}{%
  \ifdefined\thisisthewholebook\else\expandafter\yesendhere\fi
}
\newcommand{\yesendhere}{\end{document}}
%%%

%<packages and settings>
```

and the chapter files will have

```
% file chapter1.tex
\ifdefined\thisisthewholebook\else
  \documentclass{book}
  \input{commonsetup}
  \begin{document}
\fi

Text for the first chapter

\maybeendhere
```

Comment: this is exactly how I have it.

Answer (score 7):

The thing is to execute the `\fi` before the `\end{document}`.  There are plenty ways you can do that.  I'd define in the preamble:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\endifchapteronly{%
  \ifchapteronly
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  \@gobble{\end{document}}}
\makeatother
```

then use `\endifchapteronly` when needed.  The `\expandafter` expands `\fi`, then `\@secondoftwo` uses `\end{document}`.

You could also use `expl3`.  `expl3` conditionals *always* expand `\fi` before running the true or false branches:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \endifchapteronly { }
  {
    \legacy_if:nT { chapteronly }
      { \end{document} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Or, if you prefer an *ad hoc* one-liner:

```latex
\expanded{\ifchapteronly \noexpand\end{document} \fi}
```

---

P.S.: This answer assumes you are not using `\include`.  A file included with `\include` is itself read inside two conditionals, so you'd need to terminate three `\fi`.  But `\include` has its own `\includeonly` mechanism, so you wouldn't need this contraption anyway

Comment: are you sure that shouldn't be called `\stopeventually` ?

Comment: Are you sure you can do `\newcommand\endifchapteronly{...}`?

Comment: @egreg Bah, forgot about that pesky detail

Answer (score 1):

The switching between something and `\fi` can be done by `\afterfi` macro:

```
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

\ifchapteronly\afterfi{\end{document}}\fi
```